# How to add a list with a list of lists so that each index would be a list containing a an element and a list in python

Tags: python

I have two lists to start with.

Say I had a list like 
`ls_1 = ["2", "1", "2", "1"]` and a second list which contains lists `ls_2 = [[2, 7], [1, 2], [4, 6], [5,2]]`

how would I combine them into:

```
final_ls = [["2", [2, 7]], ["1", [1, 2]], ["2", [4, 6]], ["1", [5, 2]]]
```

where final_ls[0][0] would be "2"?
and final_ls[1][0] would be "1"?

I've tried to append the lists but that doesn't work

Comment: A starting point is the "zip" function. Then you only have to convert the tuples to lists.

Answer (score 3):

Use zip:

```
ls_1 = ["2", "1", "2", "1"]

ls_2 = [[2, 7], [1, 2], [4, 6], [5,2]]

final_ls = [[n,m] for n,m in zip(ls_1,ls_2)]

print(final_ls)
```

Output:

```
[['2', [2, 7]], ['1', [1, 2]], ['2', [4, 6]], ['1', [5, 2]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining your lists:

```
ls_1 = ["2", "1", "2", "1"]
ls_2 = [[2, 7], [1, 2], [4, 6], [5,2]]
```

Use zip function as follows:

```
final_ls = list(zip(ls_1,ls_2))
print(final_ls)    

# [('2', [2, 7]), ('1', [1, 2]), ('2', [4, 6]), ('1', [5, 2])]
```

Your required output:

```
final_ls[0][0]  #'2'
final_ls[1][0]  #'1'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`zip(ls_1, ls_2)` does almost what you specify.

There are various expressions which would convert that into something closer to the exact format requested. To get exactly the output specified in the question, you could use something like `list(map(list, zip(ls_1, ls_2)))` or `[list(x) for x in zip(ls_1, ls_2)]`.

However, for many applications the 2-tuples will be the appropriate data type if you do not need to modify (e.g. append to) them, in which case simply `list(zip(ls_1, ls_2))` will be adequate.

And if also you only intend to iterate over the sequence, then simply `zip(ls_1, ls_2)` will be sufficient in itself.  For example a loop `for i, j in zip(ls_1, ls_2):` will set `i=2`, `j=[2,7]` on the first iteration, `i=1`, `j=[1,2]` on the next iteration, etc.

The advantage of just using the plain `zip`, for large lists, is that you are not unnecessarily duplicating the data in memory; you are simply creating an iterator pointing to the inputs, which will get the relevant elements when needed.  The same is true of `map(list, zip(ls_1, ls_2))` if you do indeed require them as 2-element lists, but only accessed by iterating over them (`for lst in map(list, zip(ls_1, ls_2)):`).